# black banner ads admob shown in my flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

**when i am trying to use admob_flutter in pub links to create a banner ads
the output will be like:**

[image]

**but when i use my own banner ads the output will be like** :

[image]

**the same implementation way:**
https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter#-example-tab-

Comment: could you post your code implementation?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/admob_flutter#-example-tab-

Comment: the same implantation way

Comment: is your code exactly the same? Which keys are you using? You suppose to use your own dev keys.

Comment: yes,i'm sure .
i used the banner key of pub example
in my code it's shown but when i use my own banner key that is the problem !

Comment: is your account already approved? is your key for debug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Admob insterstitial display a black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891918/admob-insterstitial-display-a-black-screen)

Comment: yes, i have a developer account my banner key is a real

Comment: actually, this links does not help!

Comment: If the example key works and yours don't... I'd suggest to contact admob support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but my ads became visible as soon as it was published on google playstore. My response is a bit late though. But I believe it will be helpful to anyone in similar situation.